# Euler Lagrange equation with functional depending on function integrals instead of derivatives

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Variational analysis solves the maximization with respect to the function $q(t)$ of the functional depending on $q(t)$ and its derivative
$$
J[q]=\int_a^b L(t,q(t),\dot{q}(t)) \ dt \qquad (1)
$$

by finding the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation

$$
L_y - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} L_{z} =0
$$

where $L_y, L_z$ indicate the partial derivatives of the functional $L(x,y,z)$ .

In the case of the functional depending on the function and its integral $\int_a^t q(v) dv$,

$$
J[q]=\int_a^b L\left( t,\int_a^t q(v) dv,q(t) \right) \ dt \qquad (2)
$$

with the substitutions $u(t) = \int_a^t q(v) dv,\ \dot u (t) = q(t) $ we get the same equation. If the functional is

$$
J[q]=\int_a^b L\left( t,\int_a^t g(q(v)) dv,q(t) \right) \ dt \qquad (3)
$$

(note the $g(\cdot)$ in the integral), it can be proven that the E-L equation is 
$$
L_y - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \frac{L_{z}}{\dot g(q)} \right) =0
$$

What if the functional contains more integrals, as in the case
$$
J[q]=\int_a^b L\left( t,\int_a^t g(q(v)) dv,\int_a^t f(q(v)) dv,q(t) \right) \ dt \qquad (4)
$$
What would it be the E-L equation?

Note that when using a test function $n(t)$ to obtain the E-L equation (evaluating $J[q+\epsilon \ n]$, etc), in (1) it is supposed $n(a)=n(b)=0$. The constraint to use in (2) is $\int_a^b n(v) dv=0$ and in (3)-(4) it is $\int_a^b \dot g(q(v)) n(v) dv=0$.